# Keras | How to load multiple input (images, scalars) and multiple output (regression) data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.5, loading

I want to know what is the best strategy if I have images (RGB) and scalars as inputs and multiple scalar outputs (regression). The images are stored inside one folder. The associated scalars are stored inside a csv file.

I know how to load images and single scalars such that I feed this into a model.

But I want to know a more flexible way to load the data. I want to have different model_types (e.g. input: image, output: one scalar; input: image + scalar, output: one scala; input: image, output: multiple scalars, ...).

The files are all stored inside one single folder I also need to to split the dataset into a training and a validation data set.

Is there a concept by which I can achive this (tutorial are welcome) such that I do not have to change the whole code if the model_type changes?

Answer (score 3):

Well although the answer to your question is subject to an entire book on its own, I want to share my thoughts on this to at least get you started somewhere.

If you're using keras and want to build a bit more 'advanced' networks, such as multi-input and -output models I would highly recommend you to use the functional API (https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). It will give you more flexibility on this end. Furthermore, you might consider using `flow_from_dataframe` which allows you to read the inputs to your model from a dataframe rather than a directory - this makes your life easier once you want to aggregate data. Lastly heres a tutorial on how to combine different outputs with one another, it also highlights how to write a custom generator for that purpose https://blog.ml6.eu/training-and-serving-ml-models-with-tf-keras-3d29b41e066c

Comment: Thank you for your hints! The functional api as well as the tutorial are very good resources for building more complicated models. But they to not cover how to set up a more flexible model in which I can quickly change the inputs and outputs.

Comment: switching inputs and outputs in this workflow basically requires you only to load a different dataframe (assuming you keep the variable / column names the same) - I am afraid using keras it won't get any easier than this. Something that might be even more straight forward is the using the google vision API, however I am not sure whether this is capable of handling multi-input / output models. If my answer was able help you on this please consider accepting it, so this can be closed :)